# Upload a data file to ftp server

Tags: wordpress, ftp, public, jspdf, filezilla

I am creating a jspdf. In that, I want to use an image. The data code of image is too long and occupies a lot of space. I want to upload it to my ftp server through filezilla and use that data code in my jspdf code through wordpress. I can upload it on my ftp server but when I open the page in which the code is used, it asks for username and password. How can I make it public?

Comment: Elaborate your question. Share the script and how is it being used.

Comment: I am using cycle2, I want to use it in my wordpress page.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress and other similar CMS works differently when it comes to the headers and dependencies. You cannot simply upload the JS resource file and then use them. Even if you will try to edit your header.php or any other theme file, you are risking to make your theme stop working on WP upgrades. It is NOT recommended to do so until and unless you know what you are doing.

Now answering your question. Cycle2 has a WordPress plugin that you can install. [Click here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/cycle2/) to download it. Or even simpler, go to the Plugins menu in your WP Dashboard and search for cycle2. You will find it very simple to install and activate the plugin. Follow the Plugin Documentation/Instructions on how to use it.

Visit [this link](http://demo.chrdesigner.com/plugins/responsive-jquery-slider) to get go through the installation instructions.

Comment: Also I have created a jspdf. In it, I have inserted a an image data code. It is very long and takes a lot of space. How can I get it separately through file?

Comment: Is it linked to the same issue? Were you able to resolve your earlier issue? Please feel free to post a new question, which you will be allowed to do after 90 minutes of your recent question, and wait for the community to respond. In case if it is linked to this question only, then edit your question accordingly and give as many details as possible.